Noise from AC unit in basement
New homeowner here, I am starting to discover all the issues with my house, starting with the A/C which is very noisy! I decided to check where the noise came from and opened a couple panels on the A/C unit in the basement:


When I remove the top panel, the noise disappears. As soon as I screw it back on, the noise reappears. It does not seem to the be panel itself vibrating as I do not feel any vibration whatsoever when I push on it.
The panel has some sort of a filter on the inside, which slightly touch the motor inside, but I wouldn't say it pushes it, so I'm ruling motor displacement as a possibility. I also checked the motor was not too flush with the panel, which it isn't.
When I open the panel, there is an enormous amount of air being sucked inside via the opening. Which means when I position the panel back, this air must come from somewhere else. I have a feeling this is what is potentially causing this vibration.
Any thoughts on what could be causing this noise? Thanks in advance!
7/22 Update
AC unit looks like this atm:

Removed the filter and it’s soaked. In the space of the filter (once removed), I see this, which seems odd. Is that normal?

The part at the Red Cross is full of water and I can see some sort of green mesh inside (see previous pic). Is that expected?


if there is massive suction the filter may be bad.

your link is not working

Have you replaced the filter(s) with clean ones? (Or in the somewhat unusual for HVAC case of cleanable filters, cleaned them?)

There was no filter at all. It was missing entirely. Ordered new ones.

Turns out, the noise was a symptom, but not the root cause. The root cause was that there was a sh*t ton of water on the bottom back of the duct providing air to coil. Due to that, air flow was restricted and coil started to freeze, AC struggled and did not cool efficiently. I emptied the duct of water and everything went back into place.
I do need to figure out why the base is filling itself up over time. I haven't been here long enough to figure it out at what pace it does.
Thank you all for the various answers. It helped me one way or another :)

It's either low on refrigerant or not getting enough air. Or both. The coil should operate at about 40... not below 32. (more refrigerant makes it run hotter)

Yep, the water almost filled up the bottom part of the duct and due to that, not enough air was coming through to the coil to keep it from freezing.

That upper panel on your air handler provides access to the blower. There is a safety switch so that when the blower door is opened the blower stops running. This would explain why all sound stops when you open the door.
We can see the top of the evaporator coil (the A-shape object visible below the blower). The looped ends of the tubing should be a copper color but instead are a bright white. They're covered in a thin layer of frost, in other words. This means the evaporator is getting too cold and water is beginning to freeze to it. Freezing in HVAC is bad because it restricts air flow (among other things).
The black colored panels you noted beside the blower are not filters. They're insulation. The air filter should be in sequence "before" the blower. The evaporator coil sitting at the bottom of the stack reveals that yours is a "down-flow" configuration so a filter should be present somewhere above the blower. Sometimes air filters are installed inside the blower compartment but that doesn't appear to be the case here. Look for a removable door/panel/etc in the silver ductwork above the brown air handler cabinet. It's possible some person before you has removed the filter and didn't replace it, so you might not find any filter at all.
Hopefully you'll find a dirty air filter somewhere higher up in that stack. A dirty filter can reduce air flow and could be the cause of the frost on the evaporator. It might also contribute to the noise that prompted your original complaint.
As pointed out by Triplefault, this does actually appear to be upflow and so the filter is expected to be at the bottom of the stack.

Thank you very much for your answer. This is quite insightful!
I was able to turn on the AC even with the panel open, and the blower started, I could see it. So looks like there is no safety switch on this one.
I noticed the freezing part today when I re-opened the bottom panel after I found the AC no cooling enough. There was a lot of ice around the tubes of the coil.
At the very bottom of the unit, there is a slot for the filter. There was none, so I installed one. Interestingly, the slot was open when I moved in, maybe left like this on purpose by sellers?

The noise was gone after remounting the panels, so this isn't an issue anymore. However I now need to deal with the ice of the coil and the fact that air out of vents isn't particularly cold.

If I understand your "down-flow" diagnosis to mean the air flows downward, then I think this device is actually an "up-flow". The furnace filter is actually at the bottom, it's the long white object marked 22x22x1 just under the PVC pipe on the front. OP took it out and put a red line where it went, above the red X. Also, based on the rotation arrow on the blower, the blower's rectangular output duct would have to be visible, but it is not: it's probably pointing up.

@Triplefault Good catch; I agree that it's an upflow after all. First one I've encountered with the evap coil in the return!
